# Is there a way of writing several lines at a time to a file in python?

Tags: python, writetofile

I need to write a lot of information to a file, basically a whole webpage with certain values calculated using my script. I know I can do this using .write(), however I would like to know if you can write several lines at a time to a file, without having to put in all of the line breaks.

For example, I would like to wite the following to a file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style>
some styling stuff ..
<\style>
<body>
many more lines of code ...
</body>
</html>
```

Currently I have

```
file = open('filetowriteto.txt','w')
file.write('<html>\n')
file.write('<head>\n')
...
file.close()
```

But I would like to be able to do

```
file.write('
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style>
some styling stuff ..
<\style>
<body>
many more lines of code ...
</body>
</html>')
```

Does anybody know of a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: A Google search of "Python multiline strings" gives some good results. :)

Comment: If you're writing large HTML files look into using `templates`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use triple quotes (`'''`), line breaks are read into the string:

```
file.write('''
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style>
some styling stuff ..
<\style>
<body>
many more lines of code ...
</body>
</html>''')
```

Answer (score 4):

That's what `file.writelines` is for:

```
with open(filename) as fp:
    fp.writelines([
        '<html>',
        '</html>'
    ])
```

You also could use multiline strings with triple quotes `'''` or `"""`, but they tend to mess with indentation.

That being said, consider using [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) for HTML output.